# react js jest unit testing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, ts-jest

Inside the `Login` functional component I have a function `validateForm` which checks that `username` and `password` lengths are greater than zero.

```
function validateForm() {
  return username.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
}
```

I use Jest as unit testing tool.

```
import React from "react";
import Login, { validateForm } from "./Login";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("LoginUser", () => {
  test("validate username and password should be greater than 0", () => {
    var username = "name";
    var password = "pass";
    expect(validateForm(username.length)).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

```
TypeError: (0 , _Login.validateForm) is not a function
```

I'm facing the above error while running the test case. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to export it:

```
  ...
  export function validateForm() {
    return username.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
  }
  ...
```

But if `validateForm` is defined **inside the body of Login component (function)**, consider moving it out and exporting separately to make this test work.

```
  // Put outside and export:
  export function validateForm(username, password) {
    return username.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
  }

  const Login = (props) => {
    // And remove from here.
    // function validateForm() {
    //    return username.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
    // }

    // use this variable in the component.
    const isFormValid = validateForm(username, password);

    return ...
  }

  export default Login;
```

Comment: Login funtion is main function in that  validateForm is the sub function

Comment: If I use export function for validate get syntax error

Comment: In this case, it looks like you need to follow 2nd option and move it outside. BTW, can you, please, share the whole code of that component?

Comment: @bindushree I wouldn't move it out - test _behaviour_ (presumably this boolean is used to decide something, e.g. whether the submit button should be enabled, so assert on the outcome of that decision) not _implementation_.

Comment: Updated 2nd example to better reflect what I mean by "move out".